# CSS radial gradient not work for iPhone and Mac

Tags: html, css, ios, gradient, radial-gradients

I have this code for background style of my div and works well for all mobile device and desktop but not for iOS.
This is my code:

```css
#test{
box-shadow: -1px 0px 5px 1px #ccc;
padding:20px;
background: radial-gradient(#f7f7f7 2px, transparent 3px), radial-gradient(#f7f7f7 2px,transparent 3px), #fff;
background-position-x: 0%, 0%, 0%;
background-position-y: 0%, 0%, 0%;
background-size: auto, auto, auto;
background-position: 0 0, 20px 20px;background-size: 10px 10px;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```

On iOS, the dots in the background are shown empty and not full. How can I fix my code to see the filled dots in my background on iOS device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set below properties also as only **radial-gradient** won't work in all browsers.

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient();
background: -moz-linear-gradient();
background: linear-gradient();
```

Use this[website](https://www.css-gradient.com/) to generate those properties.

Comment: Hi! Inglese

So before my code I also have to write background: -webkit-radial-gradient ();
background: -moz-radial-gradient ();

right?